# How to solve a yaml invalid in gitlab ci

Tags: gitlab-ci

This is my first time deploying an application, so things seem a little confusing to me.
When I try to run a CI/CD test I get the error:  *jobs:docker:rules:rule if invalid expression syntax*

When I look to the .gitlab-ci.yml file I have (I'm changing the name of some variables here):

```
variables:
    rota_bian: recarteirizacao
    torre: areacorp
    sigla: aac


include:
    - project: devops/gitlab-ci-pipelines
      ref: master
      file: Stacks/python-3.8-v1.0.0/clusters/OpenShift/deploy-v1.0.0.yml
```

but nothing seems off. Where I'm making a mistake?

Comment: We need to see `deploy-v1.0.0.yml`. Find the `docker` job it's complaining about and look at its `rules:` key. GitLab has an interactive syntax checker; you can paste the YML file into a textbox once you find the right file.